How to implement Nuxt (Sidebase Auth) using your own backend (Nodejs + Express + MongoDB)
So I have a a backend:

NodeJS + Expressjs app hosted on Render
MongoDB database hosted on MongoDB
For auth passportjs

In the frontend I have Nuxt 3.
What do I want to achieve?

Username + password authentication
Auth using Facebook
Auth using Google

Can it be done with Sidebase Auth?
Using ChatGPT I find myself stuck getting the sessions to work to even load the app, currently it is in a loop of trying to get the session data "[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/auth/sessioncallbackUrl=http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapi%2Fauth%2FsessioncallbackUrl=http:%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25252Fapi%25252Fauth%25252Fsession?..."
Backend is running on localhost:3001
Here is the auth config in the Nuxt Config:
auth: {
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/api/auth',
      providers: {
         local: {
            credentials: {
               username: { type: 'text' },
               password: { type: 'password' },
            },
            authorize: async (credentials: { username: string; password: string }) => {
               try {
                  const response = await $fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
                     method: 'POST',
                     body: {
                        email: credentials.username,
                        password: credentials.password,
                     },
                  });
                  return response.user || null;
               } catch (error) {
                  console.error('Login failed:', error);
                  return null;
               }
            },
         },
         google: {
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            token: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
            userInfo: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
            redirectUri: `${process.env.APP_URL}/api/auth/callback/google`,
            scope: ['profile', 'email'],
         },
      },
   },


maybe this can help you Handling Social Authentication in Nuxt 3 with Custom Backend Logic

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
